# design a Queue that supports getMedian function

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

This is an interview question. You need to design a queue which holds integer values and has a getMedian() function that returns median element of current queue. You can use O(n) extra space.

Can getMedian() be implemented with time complexity < O(n)?

For Example:
When the queue has the following values (2, 1, 2, 2, 6, 4, 2, 5)
this method returns 2 and doesn't remove that object.

Comment: Sorry, I have changed the example now.

Comment: does the queue have a maximal number of objects it can contain? do all the other functions of the queue like push and pop need to stay in the same complexity?

Comment: You have to implement getMedian as efficiently as possible. Complexity of other functions need not to stay the same.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken this is asking for a heapque.

Comment: @user913359: do you want a *queue* + median, i.e. first in first out, or a *priority queue* + median, i.e., an arbitrary element of highest priority first out?

Comment: @user913359 : This question was asked in Works Applications isn't it ;)

Comment: @sTEAK.yes, it was asked in the advanced coding part.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The known implementation for your problem is as so:

What you need to implement is 2 heaps, one will be a min-heap and the other a max-heap.
Also you will need an integer to tell us the number of objects in your queue.

The constraints for the heaps are as follows:
1. The min-heap will have the larger objects of your queue
2. The max-heap will have the smaller objects of your queue
3. The max-heap will have the same or 1 more object than your min-heap

That way, if you have an odd number of objects the median would be exactly the max object in your max-heap. If you have an even number of objects your median would then be the average of both roots of your heaps (max of max-heap, min of min-heap).

It is important to notice that if your heaps become uneven, for instance if you will "pop" from a certain heap, you will need to remove from the other heap and move it. But thats not a problem as all you need to deal with is the roots of your heaps and nothing more.

The time complexity of getMedian becomes O(1)

Just found an article on the subject: [link](http://cg.scs.carleton.ca/~morin/teaching/5408/refs/minmax.pdf)

**Answer to comment**

The max-heap holds the half *smallest* elements.
When you add a new number to the queue, you first check what is the number of objects in the queue.
if the number you are adding is an even number, it means it needs to be added to the max-heap as both queues are equal in size.
You then see what the max in the max-heap is.
If it is larger than ur number, you can just insert it into the max-heap.
if it is smaller, meaning ur new number might be bigger than a number in the min-heap.
so you see what the min in the min-heap is.
if your number is smaller than the min, than you can insert it in the max-heap, if it is bigger, then u move the min in the min-heap to the max-heap, and insert your new number in the min-heap.
If the number is an odd number, you need to add to the min-heap as the max-heap has one more, and so on..

Its a bit complicated but if you still dont understand I dont mind psuedo coding it for you

Comment: If queue has n element then max of max-heap is greater than at least n/2 elements(i.e. elements in max-heap). But how can you be so sure that min-heap doesn't have any element lesser than max of max-heap, because if max of max-heap is greater than any element in min-heap then we have more than n/2 numbers that are less than max of max-heap. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @Yarneo: the article is about a *priority* queue, whereas the OP asked for a *queue*. I know you can implement a queue using a priority queue by giving the ith added element priority i (or -i, depending on how your priorities work), but that screws up your median computation if I understand it correctly - you'd get the element with median priority, i.e. the item in the middle of the queue...

Comment: Hey @ErikP. , thanks for the comment. There still exists a queue nonetheless, if there wasn't a queue, you wouldn't know the order of the elements pushed. The added O(n) space that was allowed in this question was the 2 extra heaps that were added which accumulate together n objects. So that means we will have 2 of the same object, one in a normal queue which acts the same as it always did, and another in one of the heaps.

Comment: I see - thanks and +1. I thought for a second that it would be slow to remove elements from the heap when an element is popped, but I guess the "traditional" queue nodes could have pointers or references to the corresponding heap nodes and then it's quick. Great solution!